# Can Applo client alone or Next js Alone would be able to do SSR in a Next+Applo app?

Tags: next.js, apollo-client

Going through several documentation of next js and applo client , i see both have methods to do SSR. And i am not able to figure out what practice to follow when i am using both in a single app. I have following queries in context with an Appolo Client-Next app --

1. if i do not set `ssrMode: true,`in Applo client, would i be able to achieve SSR by just using `getServerSideProps` of next.js? If yes why would we still use `ssrMode: true,`?
2. What difference it would make if call `client.query` otherwise `useQuery` inside `getServerSideProps`? Do one have any benifit over other?
3. Why we Execute queries with `getDataFromTree`, if i have other options like in point no-2?
4. i see this [withApollo](https://github.com/adamsoffer/next-apollo/blob/master/src/withApollo.tsx) utility for creating applo client but i don't see they are using `getServerSideProps` or `getStaticProps` anywhere, then how does it works?